# cant install a package in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

While installing a package iam getting this error.Whats the problem??

```
    Installing collected packages: opencv-contrib-python
    Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission den
    ied: 'c:\\users\\anesh_000\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2
    \\cv2.cp35-win_amd64.pyd'
    Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271291/tensorflow-installation-denied-due-to-user-permissions). May help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try installing with pip and install using super user command as below:

```
sudo -H pip install opencv-conrib-python
```

Basically in your case what is happening is that the directory where all anaconda packages are installed, there your user doesn't have write or executable permissions, which you can give and then may try installing package with anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider providing more detail i.e. installation command and package name.

Nevertheless, use *"Anaconda Prompt"* shell and type following command to install package:

```
conda install package_name
```

Alternately, you can pass environment argument i.e.

```
conda install --name myenv scipy
```

Comment: I reinstalled tensorflow environment and it works fine now.

Comment: Great, hope this discussion will help others.