# TensorFlow installation denied due to user permissions

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, junit-jupiter

I tried to run tensorflow on Jupiter netbook, python 2.7 but I realized it requiered 3.6 pythong version so I followed this steps :

Installing with Anaconda

Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

```
C:> conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
```

Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

```
C:> activate tensorflow
```

(tensorflow)C:>  # Your prompt should change 
Issue the appropriate command to install TensorFlow inside your conda environment. To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

To install the GPU version of TensorFlow, enter the following command (on a single line):

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

**

- But this line of code

**

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Show me the this error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5]
>   Access is denied:
>   'C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I tried to change user permission and also open anaconda cmd as administrator but it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried installing with "pip install --user"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989020/2091339) has the necessary information for the pip permission error. It can be resolved with the `--user` flag, which is a conservative approach.

There is another way to install tensorflow for `conda-environment`. Write below on the `Anaconda Command Prompt` after activating environment.

> conda install tensorflow

Test it :

`python
import tensorflow as tf`

And it should work.

Comment: I already import Tendorflow and already install Tensorflow but this what I get in Jupiter :
 ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.

Comment: Also I found nvcuda.dll file on the internet and added it to 'C:\Windows\System32' but nothing happend

Comment: Have you installed CUDA ? If you have a GPU machine with CUDA drivers installed, then you need to run <conda install tensorflow-gpu>.
 Its better to first test a pure CPU version, and then go for setting GPU version

Comment: Yes, "cuda_9.1.85_win10" installed but it show me " this graphic drivers could not find compatible graphics hardware

Comment: Your question was specific to tensorflow installation; so I have answered in that context only. And if you will install tensorflow according to my answer, it will help you have better boundaries for different versions of tensorflow on a single machine. According to the community rules I think you should create a new question for this cuda error.

Comment: Solved by adding --user  like this : pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. The following solved mine.

Try updating the LD_LIBRARY_PATH using the following:

sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64

I found the solution from https://abdel.me/2017/09/28/aws-ami-deep-learning-keras/

Comment: I found the solution [sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64] from the website.